# Any microstrain imu driver supporting 3DM-GX3 protocol?

Tags: ros, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Until now, only the 3DM-GX2 protocol is supported for microstrain IMUs.

Is anybody working on the 3DM-GX3 procol?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9704/any-microstrain-imu-driver-supporting-3dm-gx3-protocol?/) by [Antonio Franchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/416/antonio-franchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-04-26**:
if you supply a patch I can push it into the existing released ROS driver

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-04-14**:
Was a solution ever found here?  If not I am going to write/modify an existing package to support the 3DM-GX3 series, specifically our new 3DM-GX3-25 unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have released the patch for the 3DM-GX3 protocol into diamondback and unstable under imu_drivers 1.2.4

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "stop continuous mode" message has changed between the GX2 and GX3 versions to include two user confirm bytes. If you add these to microstrain_3dmgx2_imu::IMU::stopContinuous() it should work.

uint8_t cmd[3];

cmd[0] = CMD_STOP_CONTINUOUS;

cmd[1] = 0x75; // gx3 - confirms user intent

cmd[2] = 0xb4; // gx3 - confirms user intent

---

Originally posted by [robz](https://answers.ros.org/users/426/robz/) with karma: 31 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robz](https://answers.ros.org/users/426/robz/) on 2011-05-18**:
Sorry, didn't notice this was responded to a couple days ago.  Please see my additional comment on this gx3 thread for a more complete description of the required patch, including a critical update to the imu timer.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-05-16**:
And released into diamondback and unstable under imu_drivers 1.2.3

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-16**:
This has been patched into the existing driver. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4955

**Comment by [robz](https://answers.ros.org/users/426/robz/) on 2011-05-04**:
mwise_wg: The 4 lines above should suffice as a patch.  If you want to make the driver general, then just grab the device ID string when you initialize and check whether it is a gx2 or gx3, then wrap an if statement to choose between the 4 lines above for gx3 or the existing 2 lines for gx2.